# WPF Themes with custom theme settings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to implement theming support on my application. I know how to do it by using ResourceDictionaries on external assemblies and apply them at runtime, but I would like to enable themes that use custom theme settings and/or color palletes. I don't know what's the best way to do it.

My idea is to be able to declare a theme using markup like this:

```
<Theme Name="MyTheme" 
       Description="Simple example theme" 
       Icon="MyTheme.ico" 
       Thumbnail="thumbnail.png">
    <Theme.Settings>
        <Setting Key="EnableShadows" Text="Enable theme shadows" Type="{x:Type system:Boolean}" Value="True"/>
    </Theme.Settings>
    <Theme.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="MyTheme.xaml"/>
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
    </Theme.Resources>
</Theme>
```

Well, this code snippet is just one way it could be done. My question is about how could I do something like this in WPF (how to create a Theme class that could be used this way as a theme).

Comment: I managed to do it by inheriting from ResourceDictionary class.By merging custom ResourceDictionaries of different types, creating a tree, I can now implement custom properties on each dictionary type and, this way, control the flow of dictionaries on application using a ThemesManager class.

This gives me the ability to have a Theme class inherited from ResourceDictionary, which has its own properties (like name, icon, etc.), and have multiple SubTheme and ColorTheme classes (also inherited from ResourceDictionary) merged within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theming in WPF is a very big deal that will not be anwsered on stackoverflow...take a lot at several pro components like [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/) or [wpf toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) or an [application](http://wfpbookreader.codeplex.com/) . good luck
.